# Replacement for the deprecated setDrawerListener

Tags: android, deprecated

I am working with a the drawerLayout and using the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, I need to `setDrawerListener` but it is deprecated.

Any help will be appreciated with better replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to beginning and use `addDrawerListener` instead of `setDrawerListener`. That's it.